# Will this CryptoJS AES encryption code produce secure output?

Tags: javascript, aes, padding, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I believe that because the key passed to AES.encrypt is a string, the function will automatically generate an IV. So is the code below producing a well secured encrypted version of string_to_encrypt?

```
pass  = document.getElementById('pass').value; // user entered pwrd    salt  = 'some system determined salt';
its   = 9000 + getKeyIterationModifier(pass); // iterations depend on pass
key   = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: its });

encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string_to_encrypt, key.toString());
```

Or should I be adding 'mode' and 'padding' values to harden it further? If so, what are the current industry standard values?

In other words, should I ideally be using something *like* the following (perhaps without the iv if that's done automatically) and if so what's ideal:

```
key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string_to_encrypt, key, {
    iv: iv, 
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the user is entering a 'key' and not a 'password'?  See [point #6](https://littlemaninmyhead.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/top-10-developer-crypto-mistakes/) and note that the "awful algorithm based upon MD5" link from the blog goes to a StackOverflow post written by @ArtjomB. (the same guy who is replying to your post).

Comment: Edited code samples. The user is indeed entering a password - and as per point #6 in the blog you linked to, I'm using PBKDF2 to convert that to a 'key' in the proper sense. I've edited the second snippet now so that is working - note I had to encode the 'key' for it to work; otherwise JS threw a tantrum.

Comment: @Claud that looks better, because you are making up for the CryptoJS problem by using your own PBKDF2.  Only thing I don't know is how you are choosing salt.  Salt should not be static, needs to be chosen randomly for every time.  Also, salt is not secret. You need to retrieve the same salt as before when you decrypt it.

Comment: At present I am using the same salt each time, to generate the key from the password. (The key is then is split in two, half used to encrypt, half to mac. The encryption process uses a unique iv each time, does that not work as my 'salt' in this case then? (TY for your help btw!)

Comment: @Claud No, unfortunately not.  The whole problem with passwords is that people are not good at choosing them, so the software needs to help out to make sure that if two people choose the same password (happens often), then they do not get the same key.  The salt is solving a different problem than the IV (salt is for key security, IV is for encryption security).  See pg 119 of [crypto 101](https://www.crypto101.io/Crypto101.pdf).

Comment: You explain things very clearly, it's much appreciated. My system 'uses the same salt each time' (when converting from pwrd to key using pbkdf2) on a per user basis (in fact it uses the username, which is required to be unique) so I guess it's more secure than it sounded. But could be improved by making it (the salt) unique to every encrypt process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` uses EVP_BytesToKey to expand the passed "key" (considered a password) to an actual AES-256 key and IV if the "key" was a string. It uses a random salt for that, so the ciphertext is randomized. In your second snippet, you need to handle the IV yourself.

What you're essentially asking is whether EVP_BytesToKey is a secure password expansion function. That's not something that can be easily answered. The fact that it uses MD5 means that the first snippet has *at least* the security of AES-128 which should be good.

The other issue is that the IV should be unpredictable (read: random) for absolutely every encryption. Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. An attacker who observes ciphertexts can determine when the same message prefix was sent before. This suggestion is a given in the first snippet, but you would have to work for that realization in the second snippet which might introduce other issues.

**If you're not comfortable with CryptoJS and cryptography, go with the first snippet. Otherwise, try to improve the second snippet.**

---

#### Security considerations:

If you're using only symmetric encryption in the browser you need the exact same key at the server and the client. If you send the encryption key from the server to the client or the other way around you need to encrypt your symmetric encryption key. The easiest way to do this would be to use TLS. If you use TLS, then the data as well as key are encrypted, so you don't need to encrypt it yourself. This doesn't provide any security, just a little bit of obfuscation. You should read: https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

You should think about integrating authenticated encryption through an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or through the use of an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: Thank you! In fact the server in my application (browser based personal password and note storage system) acts only as a web accessible repository - it never needs to decrypt the data.

Comment: My encryption now splits the PBKD2F in two, encodes the halves and uses them to encrypt-then-mac precisely as per the 'old way' in this stackexchange answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/63134/146741

Comment: Only thing I would add is I don't think EVP_BytesToKey() can be considered a secure password expansion function.  Deriving a key from a password needs to be algorithmically slow to obstruct password guessing attacks, and this does not seem to be slow (based upon the reverse engineering you put in another stack overflow post).  Functions such as pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt, and argon2 are more appropriate.

Comment: I am now using the second style snippet (and hence not EVP_BytesToKey any more) in combination with pbkdf2, which runs a variable number of iterations around the 10,000 mark. It takes a fast Mac about 1 second to process.

Comment: Additional. Running CryptoJS 3.1.9-1 (unsure if other versions differ) I find that inclusion or not of: mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7 makes no odds to encryption or decryption - they are the defaults now perhaps.

Comment: @TheGreatContini Yes, I wouldn't consider EVP_BytesToKey secure on its own, but OP runs the result of PBKDF2 through EVP_BytesToKey which is not worse than a simple MD5. This is why I reduced this to the security of AES-128.

Comment: @Claud Keep in mind that the assumption of my assessment is that the second snippet also uses the `key` which was generated by PBKDF2. Also, CBC mode and PKCK#7 padding are the default in CryptoJS, but it doesn't hurt to define it explicitly.